# Laravel banned/inactive user middleware problems

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having issues creating a middleware for redirecting banned (or in this case, "inactive") users to a special view. It doesn't seem to be working at all, so there must be something missing.

Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class NotInactive extends Auth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (Auth::user()->isInactive() )
    {

       return redirect('/inactive');

    }
    else{
        return $next($request);
    }
    }
 }
```

Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware    \ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\NotInactive::class,

        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

    'admin' => [
      \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
      \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
      \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
      \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ]

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'notinactive' => \App\Http\Middleware\NotInactive::class,
    ];
}
```

User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle', 'email', 'status', 'role'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    // Gets all of the skills the user knows
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill')->withPivot('skill_level');
    }

    // Gets all of the roles this user holds
    public function roles()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user');   
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
      return $this->roles()->where('name', 'Admin')->exists();   
    }

    public function isInactive()
    {
      return $this->roles()->where('name', 'Inactive')->exists();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm missing or where I went wrong? It doesn't spit out any errors, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the new middleware in the `web` group. This will cause an infinite redirect since every route for web will use this middleware group. Instead add the new route to your auth or admin group, if not add it manually to the routes that you desire to protect using the new middleware. Also make sure you exclude the route that you're redirecting the inactive users from your middleware.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into that problem. I figured out what my issue was: I had an unnecessary relationship. But your suggestion seems to have worked. Thanks!